# Where to get lboost_system for Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

I've been getting this error trying to compile a program that uses boost:

```
undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

Doing a Google search told me to add `lboost_system`, but I have no idea where to get it. When I compiled boost in Windows it gave me several .lib files, but those don't fix my problem. I tried adding `-lboost_system` and it said "file not found." Help?

I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the full path for linking, unless you have installed the libraries in your compiler's default search path. Check out [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-from-the-command-prompt) command line example, although it sounds like you'll need the -L flag as well as the -I flag (-I is for header include directories, -L is for library include directories).